# Create CSS with jQuery (prependTo & append) will not work for Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, append

i want to create a large CSS and it works fine in Firefox and Crome, but Internet Explorer don't unterstand my jQuery script. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

```
$("<style>")
    .attr("type","text/css")
    .prependTo("head")
    .append("h1 {color: #F00}")
    .append("h2 {color: #0F0}")
    .append("h3 {color: #00F}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to add css rules dynamically (tested on majority of browsers):

```
function dyn_css_rule(sSelector, sCssText) {
    try {
        var aSS = document.styleSheets;
        var i;
        for (i=aSS.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            var oCss = document.styleSheets[i];
            var sMedia = (typeof(oCss.media) == "string")?
                oCss.media:
                oCss.media.mediaText;
            if (!sMedia
                || sMedia.indexOf("screen") != -1
                || sMedia.indexOf("all") != -1
            ) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (oCss.insertRule) {
            oCss.insertRule(sSelector + " {" + sCssText + "}", oCss.cssRules.length);
        } else if (oCss.addRule) {
            oCss.addRule(sSelector, sCssText);
        }
    } catch(err) {
        var tag = document.createElement('style');
        tag.type = 'text/css'; 
        try {
            tag.innerHTML = sSelector + " {" + sCssText + "}";
        } catch(err) {
            tag.innerText = sSelector + " {" + sCssText + "}";
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(tag);
    }
    return sSelector + "{" + sCssText + "}";
};
```

Usage:

```
dyn_css_rule("h1", "color: #F00");
```

Comment: Do you have some proof for us? Perhaps a juicy jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("<style></style>")`. IE doesn't like the single version.

```
$("<style></style>").attr("type","text/css")
    .prependTo("head")
    .append("h1 {color: #F00}")
    .append("h2 {color: #0F0}")
    .append("h3 {color: #00F}");
```

Comment: thanks morgar, but my CSS is verly large and it will be confused

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. What matters how long is your CSS? This is just one line of code.

Comment: This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Interner Explorer.

Comment: Morgar is right... And pay attention to your semi-colons, parenthesis and braces. IE is very very upset about missing ones or added ones but Chrome and FF are a bit nicer ;-)